# Search-UnifiedAuditLog for Sharepoint file and page activities dont match

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, audit-logging, sharepoint-search

I am trying to export audit logs for a particular Sharepoint site for the below operations and noticed that the count of records exported through PowerShell command "**Search-UnifiedAuditLog**"  are much less than those downloaded through the browser Audit Log Search page.  Any idea why I am seeing so much difference in logs?

https://compliance.microsoft.com/auditlogsearch?viewid=Test%20Tab
Operations -->  'PageViewed','FileAccessed','FileDownloaded','SearchQueryPerformed'

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could not reproduce your issue, I use the following powershell to check related operations, and the results will not decrease.

```
Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate "7/28/2021 12:00 AM" -EndDate "7/28/2021 6:00 AM" -Operations "FileAccessed","FileDownloaded","PageViewed","SearchQueryPerformed"
```

In addition, you could use the [Office 365 Management Activity API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference) to programmatically download data from the audit log.

Comment: So, you see the same number of results with both Powershell and from the Compliance portal as well?  Also did you test this on a particular sharepoint site?

Comment: Also, have you tried downloading all the search results from the compliance center page?

Comment: Try further test, I found the issue occurs occasionally，sometimes the number of results will decrease, sometimes the result will increase.I suggest you open a service request to Microsoft support.